# Why would a Subscription have no Payment Method Token, and how can I map it to a Customer?

Tags: braintree

I'm trying to retrieve the customer who created a subscription via its `payment_method_token`, as [described by Braintree developer agf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910980/retrieving-a-braintree-customers-subscriptions#comment43596839_15912565). However, one of my subscriptions has no Payment Method Token. The field comes back as `null` from the API, and shows up as a blank space in the dashboard:

[image: Dashboard screenshot]

The [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+python/reference/response/subscription#payment_method_token) offer no suggestion that this field could ever be empty. What can cause this to occur, and how can I find out which customer this subscription is associated with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If a [payment method is deleted](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/delete) and it has subscriptions connected to it, then the subscription will be canceled, the token will be disassociated from the subscription and you will see this in the control panel.

If there are [transactions associated with the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription#transactions), you can get customer information from the [transaction objects](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction#customer_details). In this case, it seems like the subscription never created a transaction before it was deleted so unfortunately you won't be able to trace that back to a customer.