# search for active subscription for a customer in Braintree payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, credit-card, braintree-sandbox

In my website, I am using Braintree payment gateway for both card payments and PayPal transactions with auto renewal subscriptions.

i am creating the customer and storing the card in Braintree vault for auto renewal..
also using the same customer id for that customer PayPal transactions (if happened)

before proceeding the payment, just need to check for active subscription, for both **auto renewable** and **auto renewal cancelled and still expiration date is due** subscription existence.

- is there any predefined methods for verifying that one with **.net** code?

I am new to payments, is there any recommended git projects available? so that it would helps a lot

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find active subscriptions for a given customer. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912565/5326365), "customers have a `credit_cards` array, and each credit card has a `subscriptions` array."

With that in mind, you can iterate through each credit card to grab each subscription. Once you have all the customer's subscriptions you can check their status. Here are the relevant Braintree Developer Docs links for .NET:

- [`customer.CreditCards`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/dotnet#credit_cards)
- [`creditCard.Subscriptions`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/dotnet#subscriptions)
- [`subscription.Status`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/dotnet#status)

Comment: Just keep in mind that there's also a `paypal_accounts` array which you'll have to merge with the `credit_cards` if you offer both payment methods and there's a probability that a user might have subscriptions on both.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a customer by id with the `customer.find(id)` method. It will return the customer with a `paymentMethods` property which contain the `subscriptions` associated with it.