# Braintree subscription search

Tags: python, braintree

I am working on a Braintree subscription search in order to retrieve customer IDs and subscription prices tied to these IDs. In my code I am following the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074527/search-for-active-subscription-for-a-customer-in-braintree-payments).

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(
    braintree.Configuration(
        environment=braintree.Environment.Production,
        merchant_id= 'our_merchant_id',
        public_key='our_public_key',
        private_key='our_private_key'
    )
)
subscriptions = gateway.subscription.search(
    braintree.SubscriptionSearch.status.in_list(
        braintree.Subscription.Status.Active,
        braintree.Subscription.Status.PastDue,
        braintree.Subscription.Status.Pending
    )
)

result = {}

for subscription in subscriptions.items:
    payment_method = gateway.payment_method.find(subscription.payment_method_token)
    result[payment_method.customer_id] = subscription.price

"""do something with result """
```

This approach works fine in the BT sandbox and on small queries around 100 records. However, whenever I try to query for more than about 120 subscriptions the BT server responds consistently with a 504 error. I would like to query for around 5000 subscriptions at a time in production. Any suggestions?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "BT_subscrAmount.py", line 22, in <module>
for subscription in subscriptions.items:
File "/home/karen/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/braintree/resource_collection.py", line 38, in items
for item in self.__method(self.__query, batch):
File "/home/karen/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/braintree/subscription_gateway.py", line 79, in __fetch
response = self.config.http().post(self.config.base_merchant_path() + 
"/subscriptions/advanced_search", {"search": criteria})
File "/home/karen/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/braintree/util/http.py", line 56, in post
return self.__http_do("POST", path, Http.ContentType.Xml, params)
File "/home/karen/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/braintree/util/http.py", line 86, in __http_do
Http.raise_exception_from_status(status)
File "/home/karen/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/braintree/util/http.py", line 49, in raise_exception_from_status
raise UnexpectedError("Unexpected HTTP_RESPONSE " + str(status))
braintree.exceptions.unexpected_error.UnexpectedError: Unexpected 
HTTP_RESPONSE 504
```

Comment: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node/issues/74 (BTW, there is almost certainly an error or stacktrace somewhere with more details.)

Comment: I have looked at this thread, but I am not doing a customer.find() but a subscription.search() and I am NOT experiencing this in sandbox but in production. Also, my code works with less than a 100 results.

Comment: Ok, so find the stacktrace and work out what is returning the 504 and find/ask the vendor for info on that HTTP error. The vendor defines these returns. It is almost certainly some sort of timeout. Remember, the idea with SO Q&A is that you show your research.

Comment: I have send a question with the traceback to BT, but they just told me to limit my queries. It does not make sense to limit my queries to a 100 or less.

Comment: [Edit] the question and put the traceback in as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from an amazing BT support engineer, we were finally able to figure out a solution to our problem.

The explanation:

When BT returns search results, they gather all associated data and return a large (serialized) response object to the client. In our case some of the subscriptions had a large number of associated transactions, which makes the process of fetching, serializing and returning them to the client slow. When making a request, the BT gateway returns pages in groups of 50 with a default timeout of 60 seconds. Any group with several large response objects will likely time out and produce a 504 error.

The solution:

To avoid this delay, instead of using the items method, we can use the id method from the [ResourceCollections class](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/braintree/resource_collection.py) and return just the ids of the objects. With the individual  subscription id, we can fetch the individual subscription and only the attributes we need, like so:

```
subscriptions = gateway.subscription.search(
    braintree.SubscriptionSearch.status.in_list(
    braintree.Subscription.Status.Active
    )
)

subscription_ids = subscriptions.ids

def find_customer_id(id):
    subscription = gateway.subscription.find(id)
    payment_method = gateway.payment_method.find(subscription.payment_method_token)
    return (payment_method.customer_id, subscription.price)
```

Hope this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Split your queries into small batches (5000+ subscriptions to become 50 calls of 100 subscriptions) and then aggregate as you get the responses back.  Many APIs have rate-limits and response limits hard-coded.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I end up doing. The BT API's limit is 10000 though. It's just strange I cannot get more than 120 through.